# Использование HX711 для оцифровки аналогового сигнала

Tags: arduino, электроника

Помогите, мне нужна схема того, как подключить АЦП HX711 чтобы измерять аналоговый сигнал (например звук). Я искал по всему интернету, но так ничего и не нашел.

Comment: Пожалуйста, исправьте вопрос, чтобы он отражал конкретную проблему с достаточным количеством деталей для возможности дать адекватный ответ.

Comment: https://habr.com/ru/post/438772/